# android quiz change sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on another android quiz based on a template which i found from developer feed. the app runs fine and i have altered it for my own variables but after i have entered my own 5 questions and answers into the code, when i run the app it still uses the default questions about ruby etc. is there anyway to change this and still keep the most of the rest of the code body, including the rating bar and increments? the code is below of the classes.

```
     package com.example.triviality;

    /**
     * Created by Rory McAteer on 02/05/2014.
     */

    import java.util.List;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    //imports of widgets, list and button options

    public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
        List<Question> quesList;
        int result = 0;
        int questionNo = 0;
        Question currentQuestion;
        TextView textQuestion;
        RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc;
        Button nextButton;

        //variables and button delcarations
        @Override

        //method to initialise clicker and button ids
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
            DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
            quesList = db.getAllQuestions();
            currentQuestion = quesList.get(questionNo);
            textQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            rda = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
            rdb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
            rdc = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
            nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            setQuestionView();
            nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    RadioGroup grp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
                    RadioButton answer = (RadioButton) findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                    Log.d("yourans", currentQuestion.getANSWER() + " " + answer.getText());
                    if (currentQuestion.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText())) {
                        result++;
                        Log.d("score", "Your score" + result);
                    }//if statements to find scores.
                    if (questionNo < 5) {
                        currentQuestion = quesList.get(questionNo);
                        setQuestionView();
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putInt("score", result);
                        intent.putExtras(b);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }//end of if/else to find user score
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_quiz, menu);
            return true;
        }

        private void setQuestionView() {
            textQuestion.setText(currentQuestion.getQUESTION());
            rda.setText(currentQuestion.getOPTA());
            rdb.setText(currentQuestion.getOPTB());
            rdc.setText(currentQuestion.getOPTC());
            questionNo++;
        }//increment of question numbers
    }//class

package com.example.triviality;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
//imports list

    /**
     * Created by Rory McAteer on 02/05/2014.
     */

    public class ResultActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

            RatingBar bar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
            bar.setNumStars(5);
            bar.setStepSize(0.5f);
            //get ratingBar object
            TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textResult);
            //getTextView
            Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
            int score = b.getInt("score");
            //Get and display score
            bar.setRating(score);
            switch (score) {
                case 1:
                case 2:
                    t.setText("You need to visit more festivals!");
                    break;
                case 3:
                case 4:
                    t.setText("Good effort, could do better...");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    t.setText("You know your music, O Wise One!!!");
                    break;
            }//break/case for score options
        }//rating depending on score

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_result, menu);
            return true;
        }//createOptionsMenu
    }//class

package com.example.triviality;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
//array list imports

/**
 * Created by Rory McAteer on 02/05/2014.
 */

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
//import of mini database through sqlite
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    //Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "triviaQuiz";
    //tasks table name
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
    //Column names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_QUESTION = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; //correct option
    private static final String KEY_OPTIONA = "A"; //option a
    private static final String KEY_OPTIONB = "B"; //option b
    private static final String KEY_OPTIONC = "C"; //option c
    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
    //declaration of options and database

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        dbase = db;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUESTION
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTIONA + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_OPTIONB + " TEXT," + KEY_OPTIONC + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        addQuestions();
        //creation of database questions
    }

    private void addQuestions() {
        Question q1 = new Question("\"Which year did the Isle of Wight festival begin?, 1968", "1967", "1997", "1970", "1968");
        this.addQuestion(q1);
        Question q2 = new Question("When was the festival revived?, 1995", "2002", "2006", "1998", "2002");
        this.addQuestion(q2);
        Question q3 = new Question("How many people can the festival hold?, 100,000", "60,000", "50,000", "75,000", "60,000");
        this.addQuestion(q3);
        Question q4 = new Question("How much is an adult ticket with camping?, £165", "£180", "£190", "£200", "£190");
        this.addQuestion(q4);
        Question q5 = new Question("Who are headline acts on Friday?, The Kings of Leon and Culture Club", "Biffy Clyro and Calvin Harris", "Madonna and LMFAO", "Red Hot Chilli Peppers and Beyonce", "Biffy Clyro and Calvin Harris");
        this.addQuestion(q5);
        //Questions and Answer choices with correct answer stored at the end. 5 questions in total.


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
        // Create table again
        onCreate(db);
    }


    public void addQuestion(Question quest) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, quest.getQUESTION());
        values.put(KEY_QUESTION, quest.getQUESTION());
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
        values.put(KEY_OPTIONA, quest.getOPTA());
        values.put(KEY_OPTIONB, quest.getOPTB());
        values.put(KEY_OPTIONC, quest.getOPTC());
        // Inserting Row
        //creation of new database
        dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);
    }

    public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
        //array list
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        dbase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Question quest = new Question();
                quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
                quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
                quesList.add(quest);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }//loops of array and list additions.
        // return quest list
        return quesList;
    }

    public int rowcount() {
        int row = 0;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        row = cursor.getCount();
        return row;
    }//row count
}//class


package com.example.triviality;

/**
 * Created by Rory McAteer on 02/05/2014.
 */

public class Question {
    private int ID;
    private String question;
    private String optionA;
    private String optionB;
    private String optionC;
    private String answer;

    public Question() {
        ID = 0;
        question = "";
        optionA = "";
        optionB = "";
        optionC = "";
        answer = "";
    }//declaration of variables

    public Question(String pQuestion, String pPta, String pPtb, String pPtc,
                    String pAnswer) {

        question = pQuestion;
        optionA = pPta;
        optionB = pPtb;
        optionC = pPtc;
        answer = pAnswer;
    }//declaration of parameters

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }//getID method

    public String getQUESTION() {
        return question;
    }//getQuestion method

    public String getOPTA() {
        return optionA;
    }//getoptionA method

    public String getOPTB() {
        return optionB;
    }//getoptionB method

    public String getOPTC() {
        return optionC;
    }//getoptionC method

    public String getANSWER() {
        return answer;
    }//getanswer method


    public void setQUESTION(String pQUESTION) {
        question = pQUESTION;
    }//setQuestion method

    public void setOPTA(String oPTA) {
        optionA = oPTA;
    }//setOptionA method

    public void setOPTB(String oPTB) {
        optionB = oPTB;
    }//setOptionB method

    public void setOPTC(String oPTC) {
        optionC = oPTC;
    }//set OptionC method


    public void setANSWER(String aNSWER) {
        answer = aNSWER;
    }//setAnswer method

    public void setID(int id) {
        id =ID;
    }//setOptionA method

}//class
```

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall the older version of your app and install application again ?

Comment: it's not installed, it's just one i had been using as a template on an emulator

Answer (score 0):

OnCreate function in SQLiteOpenHelper only work once; when the database file is first created, if the database ("triviaQuiz") already exists in AVD or the device you are using to test then that onCreate won't get fired,So first go to app setting of device/AVD and clear the Data of that particular application

Comment: if i clear it, it goes red with errors. would you know how to stop whichever questions are there and replace them with the 5 questions i have below instead?